# Why is this Digits Display program not working?

Tags: java, string

My goal is to output something like this:

Enter a number: 789

7

8

9

Using loop structures and basic strings.

Here is my program atm.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int mod;
    int power = 10;
    int display;
    String number;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println ("Enter a positive integer: ");
        number = input.nextLine();

    int numberLength;

    numberLength = number.length();
    numberLength -= 1;

    do {

        mod = Math.pow (power, numberLength);
        power -= 1;
        display = number % mod;
        System.out.println (display);

    } while (mod>=1);       
}
```

}

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why you do not use `String,charAt` ?

Comment: Because we haven't learned that yet.

Comment: `number % mod` <- number is a String aka Text. You cannot do a modulo operation on text, you need a number for that and you should get an error that tells you exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to any loop or any thing you can use `replace("", "\n");` in one step you can use `System.out.print(number.replace("", "\n"));` for example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");//789
    String number = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print(number.replace("", "\n"));
}
```

**Output**

```
Enter a positive integer: 789

7
8
9
```

Comment: Nice Solution!!

Answer (score 0):

use `String.charAt()`

```
        String number;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println ("Enter a positive integer: ");
            number = input.nextLine();

            for (int i=0; i<number.length();i++) {
                System.out.println(number.charAt(i));
            }
```